# How C ++ header files hold the cpp respective file definitions if they do not include them on themselves?

Tags: c++, header-files, libraries

I know that cpp libraries contains:

the
.h file (header file) in where are the function, variables and classes' members declarations and

the cpp file in where it contains the variables,function and classes' members definitions.

It includes the respective existent .h file in the same diectory.

While coding and using the libraries, it is included the .h file.

How the file holds the cpp definitions if it does not include the cpp file itself?

Comment: "cpp libraries" _do not_ contain _either_ "the .h file (header file)" _or_ "the cpp file". Those files have been processed and stuff based on their contents is in the library, but their actual content is out of the picture at that point.

Comment: What does each one of the two "file"s mentioned in the last sentence of the question mean? Please be specific and explain what "file" you are referring to, both times. This is somewhat unclear, and it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: By _declaration_ you actually mean "where they are located in binary", and by _definition_ you mean "the machine code in that location". informally speaking, when you depend on a library, you just need to know where your output is jumping to in the machine code.

Comment: and I would agree with Sam .... Question is very vague and needs refining.

Answer (score 1):

> How the file holds the cpp definitions if it does not include the cpp file itself?

It doesn't "hold the cpp definitions" at all.

A `.cpp` file (aka, a *Translation Unit*) contains *definitions*, and it can also include whatever `.h` files it needs to pull in their *declarations*.  A Translation Unit (and everything it includes) gets compiled into an Object File.  Any declarations are just references to symbols which may be defined in any Object File.

The *linker*, not the *compiler*, then brings all of the Object Files together, resolves their symbol references to connect them with their relevant definitions, and creates the final Executable File.

Thus, a symbol that is *declared* in one Translation Unit can be matched up to its corresponding *definition*, regardless of which Translation Unit actually implements it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was wondering how and why it is called the .h file while coding. Indeed the CPP file includes the necessary files including the respective.h  file too. But the .h file does not include the  .cpp file. On the source code it is included only the .h file. How the linker converts the respective .cpp file - that has the definitions-in machine code?

Comment: "*why it is called the .h file*" - because it's a **H**eader file. "*the .h file does not include the .cpp file*" - it doesn't need to. Doing so would create circular references and duplicate definitions. "*How the linker converts the respective .cpp file - that has the definitions-in machine code*" - that is too deep to cover in comments, that topic warrants its own post. There are books on compiler architecture if you really want to know the details. Just know that an object file can refer to a symbol and the linker can search for that symbol in every object file it processes. That's its job

Comment: The *compiler* compiles all of .cpp files into object files. The *linker* then joins the object files together it doesn't know about or care about the .cpp files at all. Do you really need the low level implementation details beyond that? That is going to vary from one compiler to another.